# Couldn't handle popUntil()

Tags: flutter

I have an AppRouter like this;

```
  class AppRouter {
  //static const String homeScreen = '/';
  static const String mapScreen = '/';
  static const String filterByIndoorLevelsScreen = '/filter-by-indoor-levels';
  static const String filterByLocationPointsScreen =
      '/filter-by-location-points';

  const AppRouter._();

  static Route<dynamic> onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case mapScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => MapScreen());

      case filterByIndoorLevelsScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => FilterByIndoorLevelsScreen());

      case filterByLocationPointsScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => FilterByLocationPointsScreen(
                  args: settings.arguments
                      as FilterByLocationPointsScreenArguments,
                ));

                ....
                .......

      default:
        throw const RouteException('Route not found!');
    }
  }
}
```

I am pushing pages like this `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(AppRouter.filterByIndoorLevelsScreen)`

And something like this is not working puts me in a black screen with nothing in debug console:

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName(AppRouter.mapScreen))
```

I've tried `Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.settings.name == AppRouter.mapScreen)` as stated in comments belov. Still puts me in a black screen

It works when i write `Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);` but what if i wanted to go another screen instead of the first page?

Comment: You need to return a bool in `popUntil`. So you need to check the current route's name like: `Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.settings.name == AppRouter.mapScreen)`

Comment: @st3ffb3 still not working, black screen again

Comment: Add following to your `MaterialPageRoute`: `return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SomeScreen(), settings: settings);`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by using

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(AppRouter.mapScreen, (route) => false)
```